# Error while trying to add the Admob Interstitial ad

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads

I am facing some problems when I try to add the interstitial ad.

It seems that the Android Studio accepts my code without any errors, but when I open my app - there is only a blank page and the ad banner (which was installed using the FireBase tool). If I delete the code, everything gets back to normal. I would really appreciate if you could help me.

Code:

```
package test.com.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    //Prepare the interstitial Ad
    interstitial=new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    //Insert the add unit id
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    //prepare an interstitial ad listeners
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {


        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            //Call displayfunction
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });

}
public void displayInterstitial(){
    //if ads are loaded, show interstitial ads
    if (interstitial.isLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

P.S. both, the string and the internet permission, are added.

Comment: check your logs and upload in your question

Comment: show your xml file where your banner view added ? and make sure you've Activity entry in Manifest file for Interstitial Ads

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to display your interstitial in response to the `onAdClosed` event on the interstitial itself. That event is fired when the user *closes* the ad, which means the way your code is now, it'll never get a chance to execute (in order for an interstitial ad to be closed, it must first be displayed, and your code has things the opposite way).

Instead, try calling your `displayInterstitial` method in response to some UI event, like a button press, or the transition between activities, or something similar.

Also, I recommend calling `setListener` *before* `loadAd`. Some of the `AdListener` events relate to loading, so it's best to have it in place before making the call to load an ad.

Comment: I have changed a bit my project and made a fresh start. After importing my full project, I have added the "Google AdMob Ads Activity" and copied all the code to my main activity. But now there is another problem:

When I put: 


// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;

I get an error on the "menu" - it tells me that the expression is expected. What should I do?

Comment: If you're moving code from the Ads Activity that Android Studio generates into your Activity, it may be expecting some resources that you haven't also included. If you're not interested in having a menu, you can always remove that code. Otherwise, try posting a new question here with the code, and someone'll probably be able to spot the issue. :)